Physicalism is incompatible with cognition?
So I've seen John Vervaeke make this claim that physicalism as a worldview excludes us as a meaning maker? He seems to further go on to say physicalism is incompatible with cognition.

what you have is a worldview that purports to explain everything
except how you as a meaning maker actually belong in that world at
somebody who pursues meaning and truth and can do science so you have
the problem that we generate this worldview In from which we are
radically alienated radically disconnected


that we have to think about cognition first I don't want you to tell
me how your theory of Consciousness is  compatible with physics I want
your theory of Consciousness to tell me how it's compatible with
cognition

I don't seem to understand this claim. Can someone more familiar with his claim state why this is so?

Questions should not be dependent on external resources (especially not to 2-hour videos), as that creates an additional burden on readers and makes the question meaningless if the external resource ever goes down. It would help if you could reproduce the gist of the argument here.

I've cited the relevant parts. For the most of it when this is mentioned it goes unchallenged

There is no claim here, no argument is provided. You'll find better philosophical discourse at your local pub.

Apparently, Vervake believes in 'meaning' as over and above anything physical that is needed for cognition and requires an agent with extra-physical powers to be made. So physicalism is, indeed, incompatible with his idea of cognition. Physicalists will, of course, reply that Vervake's 'meaning' is a glorified figment whipped up from something more mundane. Like consistent use of symbols and their combinations, that can be made by physical systems, like brains.

Just a remark that the Essentia Foundation (behind the YouTube channel) has a clear bias. From their website: Essentia Foundation aims at communicating, in an accurate yet accessible way, the latest analytic and scientific indications that metaphysical materialism is fundamentally flawed.

Here is what Vervaecke is saying:

Consciousness exists.  It is a real part of our world, and a naturalist perspective needs to account for it, and understand it.
Consciousness is causal.  It does things for us.  Evolutionarily, what it does for us is "cognition"
Physicalism has a variety of different definitions, but a core commonality between them is an assertion of "causal closure of the physical", which is to deny that consciousness can be causal.
Physicalism therefore cannot be a valid naturalist model of our world.

Vervaecke further objects to physicalism, because "meaning" does not appear in physics, and cannot be reduced to physics, or algorithms.  Neither knowledge nor calculation give us meaning.  He has a separate 50 lesson series on escaping the meaning crisis, providing his best understanding of how we humans generate meaning psychologically, and what practices can bring meaning back into our worldview.  Here is a good summary:  https://www.themortalatheist.com/blog/awakening-from-the-meaning-crisis-john-vervaeke To have meaning in our lives, he thinks we need to adopt many of the practices like meditation, flow, fittedness, and transcendence that have been developed by religions, and integrate them into a more naturalist worldview.  Naturalism that acknowledges a psychological life that matters, contrary to the narrowness of psychology as purely derivative as in physicalism, is needed for meaning to be fully regained.
Vervaecke does not call himself a dualist, probably because dualism has been attacked so vociferously over centuries.  What he describes at about 45 minutes into the video is a strongly emergent worldview, in which the emergent structures that grow OUT of physicalism, then have causal effect back onto physics.  One of Vervaecke's collaborators, Gregg Henriques, came up with the details of a unified emergent worldview that Vervaecke adopts: http://www.gregghenriques.com/overview-of-the-system.html
Most physicalists today are emergent physicalists, but they waffle on how "strong" the emergence is they accept.  Vervaecke accepts full strong emergence. Personally, I tend to call this "emergent dualism", as accepting that consciousness is causal back on matter is the essence of Karl Popper's emergent dualism -- and was the "heresy" that lost Popper the respect of many of his contemporaries.  However, Vervaecke doesn't want to use dualist language, and instead calls himself and his view "Transcendent Naturalism"

["causal closure of the physical", which is to deny that consciousness can be causal] Is it to? I don't doubt that most self-described physicalists do deny that consciousness can be causal and claim that this is because of their physicalism so defined, but I don't really believe that any of them derive that assertion from a well-defined "causal closure of the physical" as opposed to an independently stated a priori assertion. I'd be interested in seeing a definition of physical used by physicalists that actually excludes... well, anything, actually. +1 anyway, the answer is useful.

Good answer except for "Most physicalists today are emergent physicalists". It's unclear who you count, how you distinguish , how you got the numbers, and why this matters.

@gs Papineau, Spurrett, and Montero developed and advocated for the "Via Negativa" definition of physicalism around the turn of the century:  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-8284.00144 https://www.scirp.org/reference/referencespapers?referenceid=445032 Stoljar attempted to spell out and test multiple definitions of physicalism, and all failed (basically due to Hempel's dilemma) https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R13R2OUNXMIN6H?ref=pf_ov_at_pdctrvw_srp Link goes to my critical review of Stoljar.

@dcleve re the first, at least it excludes something! (Mental objects in and of themselves, and not as a quantitatively describable characteristic of something else, like souls or the realm of Platonic ideals.) Now if only I could find a self-described physicalist who didn't think that their physicalism implied a rejection of souls and the realm of Platonic ideals, I could congratulate that person on their functional ontology.

@tkruse -- the status of what Vervaecke thinks, and to a lesser degree what physicalists as a whole think about emergence within physicalism is crucial to answering why Vervaecke made the claims he did about the incompatibility of cognition with physicalism that the OP is asking about..  I rely upon the SEP article on scientific reductionism, plus Kim's Physicalism as my references on what is consensus.

@Dcleve, Can you give any citation from Kim about what is consensus or a majority view? I am only aware of the PhilPapers 2009 survey clearly showing a majority for physicalism, without clearly delineating between different from of emergentism. Since nobody in the world rejects weak emergence which is the same a reduction, I wonder what you mean by "Most physicalists today are emergent physicalists"? What or who is a physicalist who is not an "emergent physicalist?"

@tkruse The reference is Physicalism, or Something Near Enough.  Kim asserts that the outcome of the 50 years of debate over mind in the Phil of Mind community, once the delusional mistake of Behaviorism was abandoned, is that none of the efforts to reduce qualia are remotely plausible, and qualia need to be accepted as irreducible reals.  The way this works in the Philosophy community is that the physicalists advocates for each of the reduction or dismissal programs have not themselves been convinced their approach fails, but the consensus of their PEERS have been.

Kim did not describe it as such, but his approach to the collection of invalid rationales used by physicalists would be to treat them as a "collection of leaky buckets" fallacy.  I am not a fan of where Kim then went, as epiphenomenalism is also falsified by the Evolutionary Test Case for Causal Consciousness by William James (redeployed by Popper against Identity Theories too), and his peculiar "some consciousness is reducible and causal, some is intimately related qualia, and is not" proposed model is -- clearly a bizarre and useless kluge.

Kim holds by the "Via Negativa" definition of physicalism, and treats "phyiscalism" as materialism, and assumes causal closure, which leads him to reject all strongly emergent versions of physicalism as breaking either materialism or causal closure or both, hence not actually physicalism.  He explicitly labels functionalism a form of dualism, as an abstraction is causal on matter.

Meanwhile, for emergence, I have pointed out to you in past discussions that the definitions of emergence, and its properties as described in your Wikipedia reference are incompatible with its sections detailing what "weak emergence" consists of.  "Weak emergence" is incompatible with the bulk of the text in your own reference.  Science operates assuming strong emergence is a real phenomena, confirmed by its modeling utility, just as all other inferences to reality are.

I can easily find summaries Kims own personal stance online. What I cannot find online any trace of is Kim making any assertion about consensus or majority opinions in any philosophic community. That's all I am asking for. If you can cite directly from one of his books, that would be helpful.

@tkruse -- Well, I could dredge up my copy of "near Enough", page thru it and find the relevant paragraphs, then manually type them for you ...  OR, you could read it yourself.  I am leaning toward option B.

As long as we're in agreement that you have no online citation, and you might inadvertently misremember and mislead readers.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I suspect John Vervaeke is alluding to the problem of intentionality.
In philosophy, intentionality has the meaning of aboutness. There seems to be something in our minds (or mental states) that allows it to be about something, to represent a thing, an idea, a state of affairs. The term was coined by Brentano. It could be argued, and it was indeed argued by phenomenalists like Husserl, who was the founder of phenomenology and a student of Brentano, that all mental states exhibit intentionality. This makes intentionality a very central theme in the thinking about consciousness.
With physicalism the problem arises how our minds, fundamentally made of atoms and molecules, or better, fermions and bosons, can be about something. If we assume physicalism, we are left with the problem how our mental states, neurons firing, action potentials building, all that, can be directed to something different of itself. It can even be directed to things that do no exist.
I think this is the problem Vervaeke was talking about.
My personal ideas (not part of the answer!) lead me to think that the solution somehow has to lie in how the mind builds a model of the world with itself in it. This world represents reality, but in a way it is reality as the brain is locked up inside its dark skull with no direct access to reality. This is all we ever have and all we ever will have. What we tend to think of as reality is always the representation of reality self. In this model live all sorts of things that are absent in the real world: pain, colours, hopes, desires, your reputation on Philosophy StackExchange, all that. Presumably, it is easier to have mental states directing to other mental states...

+1 A symmetry of a sort where the internal structure corresponds to the external structure in the same way a photo captures the structure of a scene.

Meaning is not just "in the mind", or "inside our skulls". Mimicry is also a way of "aboutness" -- which shows that "intentionality" has its roots in dumb, non-conscious processes of interpretation by organisms, interacting with other organisms. Philosophers always seem to forget that interpretation has both "intended" consequences ("meaning") and unintended side-effects and that there is no sharp distinction between those two.

@mudskipper That's an interesting observation! But I would argue that the 'eyes' on the wing of a butterfly are still affecting the mind of a bird's brain. The bird effectively thinks that this means the butterfly is something else. Or would you say that it's nothing like to be a bird? Are there other examples of dumb, non concsious processesj involved in mimicry?

I'd say, there is both intended deception (Batesian) and intended honesty (Müllerian) ("toxic" colors warning a predator that a caterpillar is actually toxic or foul tasting). Also, mimicry itself should be taken in a wider sense (predator/prey behavior also works through signaling). Of course it affects the mind -- I agree with that -- it needs to be interpreted. But the interpretative process doesn't necessarily require reflective awareness. The "intention", I think, is an attribute of the complete process, the total (repeatable) interaction (rather than of an individual mind).

@mudskipper I disagree. Then you could argue that there is intentionality in a piece of burnt toast in which we mistakenly see the image of Christ. Pareidolia. I maintain intentionality exists solely in the brain. I am, however, very intrigued by the mimicry example because it seems to be co-emergent with consciousness.. I also realise now that it is easy to mistake intentionality, the philosophical term, meaning aboutness, for intention in its everyday English sense... Only mental states can be about something.

@Philomath - I don't necessarily disagree with you. But consider that signaling also occurs without consciousness. (Plants also show mimicry btw -- vavilovian mimicry resulting from unintentional and non-conscious selection by human actions -- perhaps that's even more intriguing. There it's obvious (?) that no mental states are involved -- apart from ours, in a way.)

@mudskipper Well, yes, but if no mental states are involved then we are not talking about intentionality. I want to repeat that intentionality is used here in the particular philosophical meaning of 'aboutness'. I think aboutness (to avoid more misunderstanding) is a neglected topic that is more important than most people think. I think this peculiar property of brains to be about something is key in understanding consciousness and solutions of the mind body problem like dualism. Aboutness seems easier to get a handle on and therefore might be a roadmap to understanding consciousness.

@Philomath - Agree partially. But imo aboutness does not require a human mind, just some interpretative process. First task of philosophers would be to differentiate "interpretation" from "causality". As long as that's not really clear, the mind-body problem will also continue to plague us.

You could also ask, for instance, if ChatGPT "knows what it is writing about". Or what does it mean to ascribe knowledge to it (knowledge presupposes aboutness)? Does it make sense to do so? -- I think it does, even though pretty "obviously" it's not a conscious system. -- People who vehemently deny this (Searle-like) tend to forget that meaning (aboutness) arises in the interaction of me and my world. The system was trained on tasks we are interested in. It's used in my questioning. Aboutness is best thought of as a ternary relation, not a binary one; so, in reference to an interpreter.

@mudskipper Good points. I have been thinking about all these points. AI is I think enormously useful in thinking about intentionality (and by extension, consciousness) because they are simpler models that could point in the way these states emerge while at giving us at the same time the security that there is no ghost in the machine. We know (or can know) at any given moment the exact state of all transistors. Searl's Chinese room of course, but also chess engines.

I imagine they're mostly just saying they find dualism compelling (or maybe idealism). Many other people don't.
The arguments I've seen of people arguing against physicalism or for dualism (also found on Wikipedia) goes roughly like:

It FEELS like cognition is more than just physical "stuff".
This is just an appeal to some weak intuition. And that intuition is questionable, at least to me, because I very much feel contained within my physical body, limited by physical and mental limitations and tendencies of the body I was born into, and my thinking is directly affected by what happens to my brain and body. Inject something into my blood and my consciousness disappears for a few hours. That would seem rather unexpected if my consciousness is not a physical thing.

There is the possibility of a world identical to ours, but where people aren't conscious.
This is actually mostly an argument against epiphenomenalism where consciousness doesn't affect physical events. But that's not particularly popular, and that is itself a form of dualism, so this is just dualists arguing with themselves and presenting that as an argument against physicalism, relying on a premise physicalists obviously wouldn't accept.
They somewhat try to skirt around this obvious issue by arguing that the mere logical possibility of that is a problem. But logical possibility just means "doesn't contain a contradiction". I can trivially grant that it doesn't contain a contradiction, but that doesn't really get us any closer to having GOOD REASON to believe it to be true. Lord of the Rings doesn't contain logical contradictions (probably), but I'm not expecting to see orcs running around any time soon. This is just an argument from ignorance: we don't yet have a full and complete understanding of the brain, therefore space magic. Nope.

We have some personal "identity" that doesn't boil down to potentially-interchangeable physical parts.
Like the above, that's just a premise physicalists obviously wouldn't accept. So it's less an argument and more just an assertion of what they believe.

We haven't fully explained how the brain generates cognition.
Similar to what I said in the first point, this is just an argument from ignorance.
And there is NO explanation for cognition outside of physicalism. At least not any justifiable explanation with any explanatory or predictive power. The most concrete explanation is that of a simulation (which may or may not fall under non-physicalism) - this explains no evidence and is in every way indistinguishable from not living in a simulation. "Souls" and general idealism and dualism have similar problems, but those are also a whole lot less concrete about what is actually being proposed and how that works, and how that interacts with the physical world.
Meanwhile, we have really good and extensive evidence of a really strong link between cognition and the brain (even though we haven't managed to explain the link in its entirety). We have strong evidence of the incremental increase of cognitive ability via evolution. We have strong evidence of incremental increase of cognitive ability within a single organism, as it grows up and develops its brain due to being taught and learning through experience. And we have zero evidenced instances of consciousness existing outside of the body. This suggests that cognition reduces to the brain.

People aren't able to reason under physicalism.
This is an extremely lazy, uninformed and severe-eye-roll-generating argument (can you tell that this annoys me?).
Like the point above, non-physicalists have no explanation here. The best they can do is just assert that we're able to reason... because space magic or whatever. Theists claim that God gives us our reasoning ability, but this is just a presuppositional argument that ties itself to you accepting the existence of God without actually bothering to try to explain anything - we can't reason under atheism, but we can reason under theism because reasons-just-trust-me-don't-ask-questions-just-focus-on-atheism-again. Sometimes they state that as "atheists can't reason", which is particularly annoying, and especially invalid (because the same would apply to both theists and atheists, whether God exists or not). This also struggles to account for failures in reasoning ability. They (Christians, specifically) try to deal with this by saying humans are corrupted or evil space demon tricks us or we're just evil people choosing to be evil, but none of it is supported by any good evidence and it arguably still struggles to account for large amounts of the evidence.
If a theist (or other non-physicalist) says physicalism doesn't explain cognition, but they can't provide a justifiable explanation for it under their worldview (without just asserting it to be so), then they're just using selective reasoning, with an argument against physicalism that applies equally well to their own beliefs, which is intellectually dishonest.
But actually, physicalism does provide a fairly robust explanation of the formation of accurate reasoning. Evolution provides an excellent explanation for why reasoning works - in cases where reasoning fails significantly, organisms aren't able to act appropriately in response to external factor. They just die, more often than not, and rather quickly. And quickly dying has historically not been the best way to pass on your genes. So organisms that can reason to some extent, reproduce, and pass that on, and their descendants build on that ability, and those that can reason better survive better and pass that on more often that those who reason poorly. Although, as is the case with evolution, it's all about selection pressures, and complex reasoning ability takes a lot of energy, which is a huge downside, and only really comes into it's own after a species has a relatively stable existence (which tends to be antithetical to evolution, where there's a constant back-and-forth between predator and prey, keeping either from getting the upper hand on the other, while this may be less of an issue for the species at the very top of the food chain). This is why complex reasoning ability is rare.
What evolution also provides, is an explanation for when reasoning fails, because we know it fails. People disagree about all sorts of things given basically the same information, and people believe all sorts of wild things. The adaptive view of reasoning accounts for reasoning not being perfect, because it's adaptive.



what you have is a worldview that purports to explain everything

No it doesn't. It just doesn't accept unjustified claims about things existing in some place that isn't a place (?), for which we have no evidence and which don't make much sense.

I've watched the video and found it perfectly clear and agreeable.
The only issue I could find with it, is in the terminology used by Vervake: "physicalism". "Physicalism" is an ambiguous term, meaning everything and nothing. Personally I'm fine with the idea that the mind is "physical" in some yet undiscovered sense, and therefore causal. What I object to is the idea that the mind doesn't matter,  since it is not causal, aka reductionism, and I believe that to be the real beef of Vervake, too.
Reductionism (aka what Vervake calls IMO improperly "physicalism") is the idea that the mind can be reduced to biology and that biology reduces to physics.
The problem Vervake speaks of, is that if a theory reduces the mind to something less than a meaning maker, then it logically reduces also the products of the mind, such as all science, to meaningless babble.
In short, reductionism is the belief that living organisms including humans are nothing more than a heap of atoms. If you hold that view, then you believe that you are not yourself, but a heap of atoms, that your mind is illusionary, that your own thoughts are powerless, and all sorts of odd, alienating ideas like that.

Your opinion doesn't answer the question.

I've watched the video and found it perfectly clear and agreeable. The only issue I have with it, is in the terminology used by  Vervake: "physicalism". Personally I'm fine with the idea that the mind is "physical" in some yet undiscovered sense, and therefore causal. What I object to is the idea that the mind doesn't matter, and I believe that to be the real beef of Vervake, too.

@Philomath ....

Um, yes, but the question is not what you think of physicalism. The question is what Vervaeke's claim, that a physicalist can not make meaning of the world, what that means.

@Philomath The answer lies in the assumption made by reductionism (aka what Vervake calls IMO improperly "physicalism") that the mind can be reduced to biology and that biology reduces to physics. Whatever theory reduces the mind to something less than a meaning maker reduces also the products of the mind, such as all science, to meaningless babble.

Well, I respectfully disagree. I think your sweeping generalisations do not hold. In your answer you do not connect physicalism and reductionism. You show your dislike for reductionism but you fail to explain what that means for 'meaning making'.

@Philomath  Ok, I've inserted further material from this discussion in the answer. Let me know if that works.

At about the 45 minute part of the video, Vervaecke describes his belief in strong emergence, with emergent tiers, which then do downward causation.   That is Popperian emergent dualism.  But Vervaecke clearly dislikes ever using the term "dualist", so he uses different terms.  He calls this transcendent naturalism! He also says he thinks it is compatible with non-duality, somehow.

@Dcleve I am a big fan of Popper, so no disrespect intended if I say that he adopted his pluralistic ontology not out of spiritualism and a belief in some eternal soul, but out of pragmatism: it would be impractical for a philosopher to not believe in the reality and power of ideas, so he decided to believe in the existence and causal power of ideas. This implies a belief in emergence, a concept coined by   G. H. Lewes in 1875 (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/104820/does-the-distinction-between-weak-and-strong-emergence-make-any-sense).

@Dcleve Lewes himself built upon Aristotle's notion that "the whole is more than the sum of its parts". So the idea of emergence much predates Popper. And I tend to like the equivalence between emergence and transcendence. There's much strength in that idea IMO, and I like the word "naturalism" far more than "physicalism", personally, so I would not discard the phrase "transcendent naturalism."

There are differing viewpoints on this matter:

The Compatibility View:
Supporting Cognition Through Physical Science: Many proponents of physicalism argue that cognition and consciousness can be explained through natural sciences. For example, brain processes studied in neuroscience provide a physical explanation for cognition. From this perspective, cognition is nothing more than electrochemical activity in the brain and is entirely compatible with physicalism.
The Evolutionary Perspective: According to evolutionary theory, cognition and consciousness evolved as tools for survival and adaptation to the environment, arising from material processes.
The Incompatibility View:
The Problem of Qualia: One of the main challenges to physicalism is explaining qualitative mental experiences or "qualia." For instance, the "feeling of pain" or "seeing the color red" has qualities that many argue cannot be reduced to physical processes.
The Problem of Self-Awareness: Some philosophers contend that self-awareness and our ability to perceive our own existence cannot be justified solely by physical explanations.
The Issue of Truth and Free Will: If all thoughts, including our beliefs, are determined by physical laws, it raises the question of whether we can truly access truth, or if our thoughts are merely the deterministic outcomes of material factors.
Conclusion:
Whether physicalism is compatible with cognition depends on whether all aspects of the mind and cognition can be reduced to physical processes. If such a reduction is possible (as physicalists claim), then physicalism and cognition are entirely compatible. However, if aspects of the mind (such as qualia or self-awareness) transcend physical explanations, one could argue that physicalism and cognition are in conflict.

This debate remains a core challenge in the philosophy of mind and epistemology.
